# DC analysis of N-type MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, dc

[image]

I need to solve this circuit as part of a past homework but I never really got to solving it as I never really quite grasped the mosfet all that well and soon I will have an exam out of this. Our professor uses hand written notes and not much was said about mosfets in lectures or in anything for that mattter as before this we did a bit about bjt's and that was it. I tried reading and doing some research myself using:

```
Electronic Devices by Floyd
Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra & Smith
```

as they have been recommended to me as good learning points but I find myself lost in them, are there other resources that would maybe cover circuits step by step and starting out simpler and if so can anyone provide me with some good starting points to learn more?

### Anyway about the circuit i managed to do a), b) and d), as I really struggled on them but I have no solutions to these homeworks so I can't really check if they are right. Can anyone check my work and maybe help me with c) and e) perhaps?

## For a):

```
T is off => Vi < Vth <=> Vi < 2V

So Vi would have the upper limit 2V but how about the lower limit would that be 0?

If T is off, then Id = 0
```

$$=>Vds = Vdd - Id * Rd = 14V - 0 = 14V$$

## For b):

As i know nothing about the operating region I assume one of the two possible in this case so either saturation or triode region and I check to see if it fits, regarding this I don't really know if this is the right method so if there is anything easier to be done could someone point me in the right direction at least?

$$Id = 2mA$$
$$Vds = Vdd - Id * Rd = 14 - 2 * 10^{-3} * 3,5 * 10^3 = 14 - 7 = 7V$$

### Triode region

If we are in triode region then:
$$ Id = \beta * [2* (Vi-Vth)*Vds - Vds^2]$$
$$ 2 * 10^{-3} = 0.5 * 10 ^{-3}*[2*(Vi-2)*7 - 49]$$
$$4 = 14*(Vi-2)-49$$
$$=> Vi = 53/14 + 2 = 3,78 + 2 = 5,78$$

And in the triode region $$Vds < Vdssat \\ Vi > Vth$$

$$ Vds = 7V > Vdssat = 3,78V $$

**So it can't be in triode region**

### Saturation region

If we are in saturation region then:
$$Id = \beta * (Vi - Vth)^2$$
$$ 2 * 10^{-3} = 0,5 * 10^{-3} * (Vi - 2)^2$$
$$ (Vi - 2)^2 = 4$$
$$ => Vi - 2 = \pm 2$$
So we have to values for Vi:
$$ Vi = 4V \\Vdssat = Vi - Vth = 4 - 2 = 2V < Vds$$
$$ Vi = 0V \\ Vdssat = Vi - Vth = 0 - 2 = -2V < Vds$$

And in the saturation region $$Vds > Vdssat \\ Vi > Vth$$

So $$Vi=4V$$, because if $$Vi = 0V < Vth = 2V $$

And so I have a value for Vds and Vdssat and all the rules of the saturation region are respected.
$$Vds = 7V \\ Vdssat = 2V \\ Vi = 4V > Vth = 2V$$

As for justification I'm not really sure what more I could provide.

## For d)

T is in the triode region, and I need to find Vimin.

$$Vdssat = Vimin - Vth$$
$$Vdssat = Vdd - Id * Rd$$

$$=> Viimin - Vth = Vdd - Id * Rd$$

If we replace Id we get:

$$Rd * \beta * (Vimin - Vth)^2 + (Vimin - Vth) - Vdd = 0$$

$$ 3.5* 10^3 * 0,5 *10 ^{-3}*(Vimin - 2)^2 + (Vimin-2) - 14 = 0$$

$$Vimin - 2 = a$$

$$ 1,75a^2 + a - 14 = 0$$

I solve the equation and get:

$$ a = 2.55$$
$$ a = -3.12$$

So we get $$Vimin = 4.55V \\ Vimin = -0.95V$$
But in triode region we have $$Vimin > Vth = 2V$$

And as such i get $$Vimin = 4.55V$$

Now that i got to this point I'm not really sure how to prove that it works, like what would qualify as proof of it working?